# batch start with list="path" parameters

Tags: batch-file, parameters, equals, sign

Currently my batch file looks like this

```
START "" ArtOfTest.Runner.exe list="P:\FAST Team\DLSectionAutomation\Test Studio Projects\SOFF_testing\TestLists\Main_SOFF.aiilist"

Pause
```

This issue is that the `list=` part is not passed correctly to the program.  What do I need to do to pass a parameter like "`list=`"?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not passed correctly"? What's the error? In a batch file you call a program exactly as you would from the command line, so try running ArtOfTest.Runner.exe at the command line until you can figure out its syntax.

Comment: I mean that the program returns an error that says "Incorrect test list path: 'P:\FAST Team\DLSectionAutomation\Test Studio Projects\SOFF_testing\TestLists\Main_SOFF.aiilist'  However the aiilist file is there.  The path and the name of the file are all direct copy paste from windows explorer.

Comment: Since the program is echoing back your exact path in its error message, then you are obviously passing it correctly, and your batch file is correct. You should still run it at the command line as I suggested, but my guess is you'll get the same error there. Therefore the problem is either in the program itself (perhaps it can't handle spaces in the path) or the path truly is incorrect (though I realize you don't think that's the case). I'd suggest shortening the path and removing any spaces to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely viewing the double quoted text as a new parameter, basically passing it like this

```
START "" ArtOfTest.Runner.exe list= "P:\FAST Team\DLSectionAutomation\Test Studio Projects\SOFF_testing\TestLists\Main_SOFF.aiilist"
```

Try this

```
START "" ArtOfTest.Runner.exe "list='P:\FAST Team\DLSectionAutomation\Test Studio Projects\SOFF_testing\TestLists\Main_SOFF.aiilist'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests on this. (just for info - no solution)

show.bat

```
@echo off
echo Param1: %1
echo Param2: %2
echo Param3: %3
echo All Params: %*
```

...........

```
c:>show a=b
Param1: a
Param2: b
Param3:
All Params: a=b

c:>show a = b
Param1: a
Param2: b
Param3:
All Params: a = b
```

but `notepad a=b.txt`opens a file named "`a=b.txt`"

weird...

edit:
The answer from Patrick Meinecke:

```
c:>show "a='b c'"
Param1: "a='b c'"
Param2:
Param3:
All Params: "a='b c'"
```